# Java - Find specific ID from an array(classes)

Tags: java, arrays, class, intellij-idea

Having some problems trying to call a method from a class.
Have my main method below

```
private static boolean findStudentId() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your student ID to search for your profile");
        int searchId = scanner.nextInt();
        //need to be able to find a student's profile from the arraylist by searching their ID
        return false;
    }
```

I am trying to call a method from another class and cannot do so. this is my other class I am trying to call

```
public boolean findStudent(int id) {
        for(int i = 0; i< students.size();i++)
        {
            if (students.equals(id)) {
                System.out.println("Found the profile containing information for " + id);
//                System.out.println(id.getFirstName()+id.getFirstName()+id.getLastName()+id.getDob());
                return true;
            } else
                System.out.println("Could not find a profile based on the ID you provided");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

this is my student class that I have created that proclaims the students

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String dob;

    public Student(int id,String firstName, String lastName, String dob) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public static Student createStudentID(int id,String firstName, String lastName, String dob)
    {
        return new Student(id,firstName, lastName, dob);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: What is the issue?  You are unable to call the method `findStudent`?  You are unable to to figure out the next step in your solution?

Comment: yes I am unable to call the method findStudent

Comment: Where is it located?  And where is your list of students?  Where is `findStudentId` located?  Please update your code to reflect this.

Comment: Also please copy and paste the *exact* error message you get when you try to call the `findStudentId` method.  Right now we have no real information to guess what might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add a new class and put all the methods that you are going to be using in that class then in the main class create an object and you could easily use that methods with no problem

+small note the condition in findStudent method should be like

```
if (students.get(i).id == id)
```

so it would search for the id in the arraylist

Comment: thanks mate just forgot to add a simple .get(i).id in the end

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method from another class you can for example create an object of the class you are trying to get the method from. For instance...

If the method you have is located inside of Class A, then create an object of that class.

```
A classAttribute = new A();
```

Then to call the method use....

```
classAttribite.someMethod();
```